# Formatação de data no campo Aniversário

Tags: bug, status-pronto, perfil

O `placeholder` do campo Aniversário do perfil está com a marcação de data BR: DD/MM/AAAA, porém se colocar uma data nesse formato dá o seguinte erro:

> Oops! Houve um problema ao atualizar seu perfil: O aniversário deve
>   ser no formato aaaa/mm/dd

Comment: Eu ia mencionar isto, porém você foi mais rápido... xD

Comment: Também iria mencionar. Mas tal como o Kenny falou, você foi mais rápido. Mas gente, passaram-se dois meses e o problema continua!